# How to link library in Ada with GNAT on Fedora 17?

Tags: gcc, fedora, ada, gnat

I try to compile unit with ada-zlib. Package ada-zlib-dev is installed. In code I write `with Ada.Text_IO;`. GNAT Reference Manual states that additional compiler arguments are not required if library is located in directory from ADA_INCLUDE_PATH environment variable. But it's empty. How should I set that variable to get code compiled?

---

**UPDATE:**

The code is [read.adb](http://zlib-ada.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zlib-ada/zlib-ada/read.adb?revision=1.8&view=markup) from zlib-ada. It's provided as an example. Command line:

```
gnatmake read.adb
```

Comment: There's much more to compiling than properly setting ADA_INCLUDE_PATH. Post your code so we have some idea of what you're doing.

Comment: Have you followed the [`readme.txt`](http://zlib-ada.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/zlib-ada/zlib-ada/readme.txt?revision=1.21&view=markup) for GNAT?

Comment: So I have write something like `gnatmake read.adb -L<directory where lib is> -lada-zlib`? Shouldn't <directory where lib is> be in any INCLUDE var?

Comment: If you use -I, -L, etc, you shouldn't have to set ADA_INCLUDE_PATH. In addition, in your example statement above, -L and -l are linker options, so you should add -largs: `gnatmake read.adb -largs -L<dir> -lada-zlib`

Comment: Is your package really ada-zlib rather than zlib-ada? Is there a `.gpr` file alongside `read.adb`? If so, try `gnatmake -p -P <whatever>.gpr`.

Comment: Bascially, ADA_INCLUDE_PATH is for stuff you use so often that you don't want to bother putting it in your `-L` directory list all the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found answer finally.

It isn't necessary to set environment variables. The .gpr files for the libraries are located in /usr/lib/gnat. You need to write such .gpr file for your project:

```
with "<name of lib's .gpr file related to /usr/lib/gnat";
project SUFO is
        for Source_Dirs use ("src");
        for Object_Dir use "obj";
        for Exec_Dir use "bin";
        for Main use ("src/main.adb");
end SUFO;
```

And run `gprbuild` command in project directory, where you've placed your .gpr file.